# Entity Framework Entity SQL Query for Left Outer Join that returns Nulls from count on Virtual Collect

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, null, left-join

I'm trying to write a Entity SQL query on a virtual collection in a table.

The main model looks like this:

```
public class Person { 
        [Key] 
        public string person_id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Media> Media { get; set; }

        public string username { get; set; }
    }
```

And the virtual collection is defined like this:

```
public class Media
        {
            [Key]
            public string media_id { get; set; }

            public string UserId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("UserId")]
            public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

            public DateTime? created_time { get; set; }
        }
```

I want to find the NULL's or where virtual collection is zero.

I have implemented the following but it seems like it does an equal join, rather than a left outer join.

```
var people = await db.People.Where(q => q.Media.Count() == 0).ToListAsync();
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with await db.People.Where(q => q.Media == null || !q.Media.Any()).ToListAsync();

Comment: Any() still produces the same result as an equal join and it's not possible to a compare of null on an iCollection because null is supposed to be zero.

Comment: mjwills, I wrote the sql statement doing the left outer join, the result wasn't correct. The result excludes the nulls.

Comment: Please update your post to show the data in the database, what the query **is** returning and what you **want** it to return.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the data is, any Person with no Media, which should be zero, is not returned.

Comment: My core question is how do you do a one to many join on a virtual collection with no key value.

Comment: Both `db.People.Where(q => q.Media.Count() == 0)` and `db.People.Where(q => !q.Media.Any())` should produce correct results. What is the generated SQL, i.e. what do you see if you evaluate  `db.People.Where(q => q.Media.Count() == 0).ToSTring()` in the debugger?